# How to use AVSpeechSynthesizer to read a UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech, uilocalnotification, avspeechsynthesizer

I have an objective-c application that receive local notifications. I want read the alertBody of notification when this will be showed to user on his iPhone in background. How can I do this?

I'm trying this code, but not works:

Here I load my local notification while the app is in background, and I load speak function that should be said the alertBody text.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"key1", @"1", nil];
        notification.userInfo = infoDict;
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can you hear this notification?"];
        notification.soundName =  @"Alarm-Clock.caf";
       [self speak:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", notification.alertBody]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

@property (strong, nonatomic)  AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer;



 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    self.synthesizer.delegate=self;


    ...
    }


-(void) speak:(NSString *) text{
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:texto];
    utterance.volume = 1.0;
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_3)
    {
        utterance.rate = 0.15;
    }else{
        utterance.rate = 0.45;
    }
    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance
{

}
```

And I have added AVFoundation framework, background modes and Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture in capabilities.

How could I change my code to speak the alertBody of my UILocal notification?